# how to make jslint support Chinese word?

Tags: jslint

everyone

I know Chinese words Unicode between \u4E00-\u9FA5  and \uF900-\uFA2D , so I modify the 
jslint source code:

```
//cx = /[\u0000-\u0008\u000a-\u001f\u007f-\u009f\u2028\u2029\ufff0-\uffff]/,
cx = /[\u0000-\u0008\u000a-\u001f\u007f-\u009f\u2028\u2029\u4E00-\u9FA5\uF900-\uFA2D\ufff0-\uffff]/,
```

but still failed.
any one could give me a hand?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this really what you are trying to parse? Its commented out, and you have a comma after the first declaraion

Answer (score 0):

You code is commented out, so JSLint should ignore it. what is the error message that you are getting?

You also have a comma after the first declaration.

If you write it like this, then it passes:

```
var cx = /[\u0000-\u0008\u000a-\u001f\u007f-\u009f\u2028\u2029\ufff0-\uffff]/;
cx = /[\u0000-\u0008\u000a-\u001f\u007f-\u009f\u2028\u2029\u4E00-\u9FA5\uF900-\uFA2D\ufff0-\uffff]/;
```

Comment: [jslintant] jslint: 4 Problems found in C:\wamp\www\style_bp\js\promotion\wxbaction.js
[jslintant] Lint at line 1 character 1: Unsafe character.
[jslintant] 锘?**
[jslintant] 
[jslintant] Lint at line 1 character 1: Unexpected '锘'.
[jslintant] 锘?**
[jslintant]

Comment: Can you edit your original answer to contain that info, please. Also, can you detail how you are doing the scan (i.e. locally, or through the web page). Also, have you got any options set.

Comment: (function(w) {
        var staticMode=false;
        var $ = jQuery;
        w.print=function(){
        };
    })(window);

does jslint do not support js auto execute style?